# How to rename to existing folder

Tags: linux, unix, shell-script

i am not able to rename the folder name. i tried these ways. please correct me,

```
[testuser@backupdev1-lnx backup]$ cd /opt/backup/    
[testuser@backupdev1-lnx backup]$ ls -l
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 testuser testuser 4096 May 14 21:46 deployables
drwxrwxr-x 3 testuser testuser 4096 May 14 21:46 deployables_05_14_2013
[testuser@backupdev1-lnx backup]$ rename deployables deployables_$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")
[testuser@backupdev1-lnx backup]$ ls -l
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 testuser testuser 4096 May 14 21:46 deployables
drwxrwxr-x 3 testuser testuser 4096 May 14 21:46 deployables_05_14_2013
[testuser@backupdev1-lnx backup]$
[testuser@backupdev1-lnx backup]$ mv -f deployables deployables_$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")
mv: cannot move `deployables' to a subdirectory of itself, `deployables_05_14_2013/deployables'
[testuser@backupdev1-lnx backup]$
```

Comment: Please show `ls -l` instead of just `ls`. I wonder if perhaps `deployables_05_14_2013` is a symlink to `deployables`.

Comment: Also, it looks like you are using the mm dd yyyy convention for date formats. This convention is illogical and problematic because it is neither more-significant-toward-less-significant nor less-significant-toward-more-significant. You should consider using ISO 8601's YYYY-mm-dd (most-significant-to-least-significant), or, failing that, at least use dd-mm-YYYY (least-significant-to-most-significant).

Comment: i changed my request. please check

Comment: @Celada the mm dd yyyy is the natural way to write dates for English speakers since that is how dates are spoken, for example May 15th, 2013. As a European, I am more used to 14/05/13 but the US convention is 05/14/13.

Comment: @terdon It may be natural in spoken English where you say the name of the month, but I don't find it natural at all in writing. On a more objective note, the biggest flaw of this format is that it is probably going to get misinterpreted whenever the day number is 12 or less (because it looks like a month number). The workaround for this is to use the month name instead of number... which is exactly what is done in speech.

Comment: @kumarM I don't know... I guess there had to be something already existing inside the `deployables_05_14_2013` directory but no matter what I try I cannot reproduce the "subdirectory of itself" error message. As for the `rename` command, I was unfamiliar with this command but I read the manpage. It looks like you are using it incorrectly: the first argument is supposed to be a Perl substitution command, not a filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page at [www.tuxfiles.org](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/dirman.html) provides good information on manipulating directories in Linux. Since it appears you want delete the existing directory, the following command(s) will suffice:

```
rm -r deployables_$(date +"%m_%d_%Y"); mv deployables deployables_$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")
```

The `mv` command does does not overwrite directories and the destination needs to be removed before hand with the `rm -r` command. This will generate a harmless error if the source directory does not already exist.

Comment: Exactly @terdon. If the destination is a directory, the source file, file or directory, is placed _into_ the destination, not overwriting the destination.

Comment: Ummm... reading my comment again, I have no idea what I was talking about... Comment deleted, upvote added.

Comment: I got solved, that my mistake, actually "deployables_05_14_2013" folder already exist, so it not able to rename to the "deployables" to "deployables_05_14_2013" again. So it is not working. i added time and date both, then it working.

Answer (score 0):

I got solved,

That my mistake, actually "deployables_05_14_2013" folder already exist, so it not able to rename to the "deployables" to "deployables_05_14_2013" again.

So it is not working. i added time and date both, then it working.